# c# сокеты клиент-сервер (запись в файл)

Tags: c#, сокет, клиент-сервер, сокеты

У меня небольшая проблемка в работе с клиент-сервером.

Суть моего задания в том, что мне нужно, чтобы клиент ввел номер строки и текст, который будет записан в текстовый файл, а этот файл должен хранится на сервере.

Я, знаю как сделать все части отдельно, но как совместить их воединно не знаю. Вот в целом вопрос в чем.
У меня полнаая запара при конвертации в байты и обратно ....

Прошу помочь ссобрать все части воедино

**КЛИЕНТ**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
class Program
{
static Socket socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    socket.Connect("127.0.0.1",904);
    Console.WriteLine("Vvedite nomerk stroki");
    int number_line =Convert.ToInt32( Console.ReadLine());
    Console.WriteLine("Vvedite text");
    string line_text = Console.ReadLine();
    byte[] buffer1 = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(number_line);
    byte[] buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(line);
    socket.Send(buffer);
    socket.Send(buffer1);
    Console.ReadKey();
}
}
```

**СЕРВЕР**

```
class Program
{
static Socket socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    socket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 904));
    socket.Listen(5);
    Socket client = socket.Accept();
    Console.WriteLine("Подключение к серверу");
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    byte[] buffer1 = new byte[1024];
    client.Receive(buffer1);
    client.Receive(buffer);
    Console.WriteLine(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer));
    Console.WriteLine(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer1));
    Console.ReadKey();
}
}
```

**ЗАПИСЬ В ФАЙЛ ПО НОМЕРУ СТРОКИ**

```
var text = File.ReadAllLines("1.txt").ToList();
text.Insert(number_line,line_text);
File.WriteAllLines("1.txt", text.ToArray());
```